# mod_rewrite RewriteRule pattern match fails when query string is URL-encoded

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite RewriteRule, and in my RewriteRule, I am trying to match a URL that has query string that looks like:

http:///myfakeoam/obrareq.cgi?....

My RewriteRule looks like:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^wh=(.*)$    [NC]

RewriteRule ^/myfakeoam/obrareq.cgi$ http://apache1.whatever.com/formbasicprotected/index.html [CO=wh:%1:.whatever.com:1440:/]

When I test manually, by manually typing the URL into the browser, that RewriteRule seems to be able match a request if the request looks like:

http:///myfakeoam/obrareq.cgi?wh=xxx&ru=yyyy&....

but, in my actual system, the request is being created by anoher app, and it appears to be URL-encoding (actually URL-encoding twice) the query string (e.g, replacing equal with "%3D", etc.), i.e.:

http:///myfakeoam/obrareq.cgi?wh%3Dxxx....

And if the query string part is URL-encoded like that the pattern match in my RewriteRule is not failing...

Is there any way to handle this situation?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I guess that the reason the other app is double-URL-encoding the query string is because of something like this (http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2008/03/20/mod_rewrite-urlencode-and-special-characters/)?  But then, can I make a RewriteRule that works with that incoming request?  Jim

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, I just realized that the RewriteCond was just doing a regex match for the query string, so I changed that to:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^wh%3D(.*)$ [NC]

and then it worked.

Jim